Angular Login/Logout Behavior
I have a question.  I have an application with Login and Logout which works, but with a hiccup.
Here is the scenario.  Using Observable, When user logins in it shows there user name, when they logout it removes name which is fine and redirects to login page,  which is fine. Lets say the user doesn't want to login at time of the redirect and navigates to another page, then decides they want to login, this is where I encounter the issue, clicking on the login page takes them to home page and won't let then login, which is the behavior as if they are already logged in.
When I go to application on developer tools it clearly shows the status of 0, which means login Status is false. I'm doing testing for when the user does not follow the logic meant for the application.
Any ideas or thought?  Point me any the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Difficult to understand the problem. Could you please share a code samples or create an example on stackblitz? In addition, you haven't mention what type of authentication/authorization are you using. Is it something custom, or SSO, etc.?
